# Java split() into new String[]

Tags: java, string, split

Is it possible to split a string into an string array that hasn't been declared?

I want to add a string array to a list, so currently I have it set like this `vars.add(new String[]{s});` where `s` is a string. Is there anyway to make it add `s.split("|")`?

Or is the only option:

```
String [] ns = s.split("|");
vars.add(ns);
```

I was playing in netbeans, where I would this make a string array, with this string `"A|C|D|E"`:

```
new String(s).split("|");
```

Comment: Split creates an array of substrings by default, so if your method accepts array as an parameter, there is no reason why you could not use s.split() as parameter to pass the array to the method. You will probably just need to alter what your method does on the other side.

Comment: `.split()` returns an array of String. Is that what you are asking?  In Java, arrays and collections are different and don't play together well.  You can use `.addAll()` on a collection, and the `Arrays.asList()` to wrap an array in a lightweight implementation of `List`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
ArrayList<String[]> vars = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String s = "A|C|D|E";
vars.add(s.split("\\|"));
```

Note that if you want to add the `Strings` individually to the list, you must do it slightly differently.

```
ArrayList<String> vars = new ArrayList<String>();
String s = "A|C|D|E";
for (Sting str : s.split("\\|"))
    vars.add(str);
```

Comment: Heh, yea that would work huh. I was set on making a new string since the previous method i took it from, did some replacements with the string, so i couldn't add the original

Comment: You never need to make a new string.

Comment: So this works for my original question, but now for some reason it wont actually split my string at the "|" characters. It just splits the entire string so each character has its own position in the array.

Comment: @Eric: That's because the | has special meaning in regex, you need to escape the |.  this ought to be `s.split("\\|")`   :-)

Comment: @NathanHughes Good catch!